# Libgdx | Do emulators normally stutter/lag during gameplay?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

My games works fine on my turbo 1 and turbo 2 physical devices. But on an emulator, it is has bad lag spikes. Almost unplayable. Could this be a problem with my code? Maybe an incompatibility with some devices and shaderPrograms? Or is this someone wrong with emulators themselves? The emulator is the one built into android studio. Thanks for your help!

Comment: The emulator is pretty much useless for testing OpenGL. When you create a virtual device, you can set the Emulated Performance setting to Hardware to get it to directly use desktop OpenGL. This will speed it up considerably, but you'll be missing out on possible OpenGL ES errors.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, from personal experience of using Android Studio, the emulator is ridiculously slow. 1/100 it will be your code. If it works on your phsyical devices, it should be fine.